# How can I see a list of products that customers have asked to be alerted on?

Tags: magento-1.6, stock, alert, stock-status

I was looking in the admin area for a place to see products customers have chosen to be alerted on. This seems like a useful feature considering you may want to re-stock those products since they will sell fast. I couldn't find any way to do it though. I also want to use it for testing to make sure these are working correctly.

Also, while reading this other question ([Are stock and price alerts ever removed?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17983/are-stock-and-price-alerts-ever-removed)) it made me think there was a way for customers to see products they have chosen to be alerted on, and unsubscribe from those alerts, however I can't find a way to do that either.

I found this article with a way to list them out for each customer (http://magenting.wordpress.com/2011/12/05/get-customer-product-alert-subscriptions-list-in-magento/), but I was wondering if there was any built in functionality for this.

Are either of these things possible? I'm using Magento 1.6.2.0

Comment: hey are you want to see list product alert with customer details in a grid view?

Comment: I was more just trying to see if there was a built in feature for this without having to install an extension. That would be preferred, though, yes.

Answer (score 1):

You can show the products alerts statistics in admin for all customers using collection like

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $productsTable = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('catalog/product');
    $c = Mage::getModel('productalert/stock')->getCollection();
    $c->getSelect()
        ->columns(array('cnt' => 'count(*)', 'last_d'=>'MAX(add_date)', 'first_d'=>'MIN(add_date)'))
        ->joinInner(array('e'=> $productsTable), 'e.entity_id = product_id', array('sku'))
        ->where('send_count=0')
        ->group(array('website_id', 'product_id'))
    ;

    $this->setCollection($c);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

It's form the [free alerts extension](http://amasty.com/product-alerts-reports.html).